# In Foundation 4 css h1 first letter text transform capitalize causes missing letter in topbar h1 name

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

The custom CSS that I added to allow for the first letter in H1 to capitalize everywhere is making the first letter "X" of topbar with title starting XYZ disappear.

I've unsuccessfully tried:

```
.topbar:first-letter {
  text-transform: none !important;
}

.top-bar .name {
  text-transform: none !important;
}
```

---

```
<nav class="top-bar">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <!-- Title Area -->
    <li class="name">
      <h1><a href="#"class="home" title="XYZ Business Lobby">XYZ Business Lobby</a></h1>
    </li>
    <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon        `enter code here`alone -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/setbon/5HzKL/).

Comment: It's not really missing, it's just that you can't see it because you made it black

Comment: Thank you very much onetrickpony- that was it!